# Distance to a convex set and the inner product

Tags: real-analysis

so I have a fairly simple question on real analysis that I can totally geometrically agree, but my attempts to prove failed.
Let $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ closed and convex and let $a \in \mathbb{R}^N, y_0 \in B$ such that $∥a − y_0∥ = d(a, B)$.

Show that

$$⟨x − y_0, a − y_0⟩ ≤ 0, ∀x ∈ B.$$

The idea I pursued the most was to suppose by contradiction that there is an $x\in B$ s.t $⟨x − y_0, a − y_0⟩ >0 $ and try to prove the distance between $x$ and $a$ is less than $||y-a||$, but I did not manage to do it, and it does not seem to use the convexity hypothesis very well. Could anyone help?

Comment: Since $B$ is a closed convex subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it is a closed interval whose ends are allowed to be $\pm\infty$ and the inner product is just the usual multiplication.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was supposed to be in $\mathbb{R}^N$, correcting now.

Comment: This is the first-order optimality conditions for the optimisation problem $\inf_{b\in B}\|a-b\|$ and you know here that the solution is attained at $b=y_0\in B$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $x\in B$, then $d(x,a)\ge d(y_0,a)$, which leads to $\vert\vert a-x\vert\vert^2\ge\vert\vert a-y_0\vert\vert^2$. Writing $a-x=(a-y_0)-(x-y_0)$, we can see that:

$$\vert\vert a-x\vert\vert^2=\vert\vert a-y_0\vert\vert^2+\vert\vert x-y_0\vert\vert^2-2\langle a-y_0,x-y_0\rangle$$

which $\ge\vert\vert a-y_0\vert\vert^2$. Rerranging this gives the desired inequality, noting trivially that $\vert\vert x-y_0\vert\vert^2\ge0$

Geometrically, note that $\langle x-y_0,a-y_0\rangle=0$ is a plane, so this result shows that given a point $a\notin B$, there is a plane which $a$ and $B$ lie on opposite sides of.